# Angular2 adding parameters to the router url

Tags: angular, typescript

Am new to angular2 and am looking forward to add parameters to a router when the current url doesnt have the said param on click event

This is what i have tried

The button

```
<button (click)="onStats()">Proceed to stats </button>
```

Now the function

```
onStats(){
    let url = this.router.url;

    //here i would like to check if the router constains ?stats
    //am stuck

}
```

So basically i have my urls as

```
locahost:4200/users/roles
localhost:4200/managers
...............
```

now i would like to add  ?stats at the end of url if it doesnt exists hence the new url to be

```
locahost:4200/users/roles?stats
locahost:4200/managers?stats
...........
```

In my routing i have setup

```
{path:'user/roles:stats' , component:UserRolesStats}
```

How do i go about it

I would not like to hardcode the routerlink="users/roles?stats" since other areas also use this stats functionalities as well

Answer (score 5):

#### Inspect current query params

Use the `ActivatedRoute` service to subscribe to the *query parameters* of the current route. You can inspect if *?stats* exists like this:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
private stats: boolean;    

ngOnInit() {
    this.route
      .queryParams
      .map(params => params['stats'])
      .subscribe(stats => this.stats = !!stats);
  }
```

A lot of good information to read in the [official docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#query-parameters-and-fragments):

> *Query Parameters* and *Fragments* are also available through the
>   `ActivatedRoute` service. Just like route parameters, the query
>   parameters and fragments are provided as an `Observable`

#### Adding query params during navigation

To prepend a query parameter when you navigate, you can add the `NavigationExtras` parameter to the `.navigate()` method of the `router` or add the `[queryParams]` directive to your link.

From code:

```
this.router.navigate(['/users/roles'], { queryParams: { stats: true } });
```

From template:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/users/roles']" [queryParams]="{ stats: true }">
```

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI added some more to the answer. Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I use "import { Router } from "@angular/router";" and this allows me to do the following function and more.

```
  this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params)=> {
  //check lead Id here
  if(params['id']){
    console.log(params['id']);
  } else {
    console.log('id not found in params')
  }
});
```

Here is a link to example of how to navigate and add parameters to your url and much more. [Angular2-routing](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/routeparams.html)